# Simular Login em Um site

Tags: javascript, node.js, login, axios

Fala devs, estou o dia inteiro tentando implementar uma forma de fazer login em um site com JavaScript, é o site de minha universidade, e gostaria de monitorar quando novas notas forem lançadas, pra eu não ter que entrar nesse site pra verificar se minhas notas foram lançadas ou não, além disso o site machuca meus olhos de feio. já tentei várias formas que achei internet a fora, o ultimo que tentei foi algo assim:

```
axios.post('https://sigaa.uepa.br/sigaa/logar.do?dispatch=logOn', {
    "user.login": 'myLogin', 
    "user.senha": 'myPsw'
}, {headers: {'Accept': 'application/json'}})
        .then(function (res) {
            //Função que vai tratar o html e extrair as notas
            extractNotes(res)
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.error(error);
        });
```

Acho que esse código pode explicar de forma mais clara o que eu quero, no entanto ele não está logando e está me retornando a página de login de volta, como se eu nem tivesse tentado fazer login.

Muito grato se alguém conseguir me ajudar

Comment: Dependendo da implementação do site, a maioria cria um token de sessão e salva em algum lugar que deve ser passado nas próximas páginas de acesso restrito a quem está logado para que o conteúdo possa ser exibido.

Comment: @MarceloBoni Esse site realmente faz isso, no entanto ele não está me retornando o token nem nada do tipo, ele simplesmente está me redirecionando para a tela de login

Comment: Usa o [Puppeteer](https://pptr.dev/)